# Conditionally set a variable/parameter in an SSIS Expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I'm trying to set a variable/SQL parameter conditionally based on the value of User variable in SSIS package.  If ReprocessBatch equal 0 than set @SuccessFailure = 'S' ELSE set @SuccessFailure = 'RS'

Is this doable?  If so what is the syntax?

`( @[User::ReprocessBatch] == 0? @SuccessFailure='S':@SuccessFailure= 'RS'),`

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for a late posting, I just happened to see your post while googling for something else. I am sure you would have found the right way to assign a variable conditionally, in an expression task. But if you haven't, this is how I do it:

Inside Expression Task:
@SuccessFailure = (@[User::ReprocessBatch] == 0 ? 'S' : 'RS')

Answer (score 1):

I found it couldn't be done as I was attempting to do it.  I was trying to set the parameter value from within a SQL Task expression that called a stored procedure.

To resolve I had to add a package variable called @SuccessFailure and map the parameter in the SQL Task.

Steps:
1)  Add Package variable SuccessFailure and set expression to: 
`( @[User::ReprocessBatch] == 0? "S":"R")`
2)  In SQL Task Parameter mapping, add Variable Name: 
`User::SuccessFailure of type string and Parameter Name of @SuccessFailure`
3)  Edit SQL Task Expression that calls Stored Procedure to: 
`"exec etl." + @[User::ProjectName] + ".EndETLLog 
@SuccessFailure= @SuccessFailure;"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Refer to MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx

Also am not sure of your requirement. Also checkout precedence constraints. It might help